# how to join two dataframes and substract two columns from the dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes which look like below
I am trying to find the diff between two amount based on ID

Dataframe 1:

```
ID  I Amt
1   null 200
null   2 200
3   null 600

dataframe 2

ID I  Amt
2  null  300
3  null  400

Output
Df
ID Amt(df2-df1)
2  100
3  -200
```

Query doesnt work:
Substraction doesnt work

```
df = df1.join(df2, df1["coalesce(ID, I)"] == df2["coalesce(ID, I)"], 'inner').select
((df1["amt)"]) – (df2["amt”])), df1["coalesce(ID, I)"].show())
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Subtraction doesn't work`?.  Additionally, what are you trying to accomplish with the coalesce on the joins?

Comment: coalesce is a function which returns a non null value, in this case are IDs...I am joining on the value returned from coalesce function. In addition to that I want to display the difference amount along with the ID(derived from coalesce function)

Comment: I understand how coalesce works.  In your sample data, you have no nulls.

Comment: Changed the data to reflect the same

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple of things differently.  To make it easier to know what column is in what dataframe, I would rename them.  I would also do the coalesce outside of the join itself.

```
val joined = df1.withColumn("joinKey",coalesce($"ID",$"I")).select($"joinKey",$"Amt".alias("DF1_AMT")).join(
df2.withColumn("joinKey",coalesce($"ID",$"I")).select($"joinKey",$"Amt".alias("DF2_AMT")),"joinKey")
```

Then you can easily perform your calculation:

```
joined.withColumn("DIFF",$"DF2_AMT" - $"DF1_AMT").show
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|joinKey|DF1_AMT|DF2_AMT|  DIFF|
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|      2|    200|    300| 100.0|
|      3|    600|    400|-200.0|
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```